# Encryption of AES(128/ECB/PKCS5)+Base64(RFC 1521) in Java and decryption in Golang

Tags: java, go, cryptography, base64, aes

the Encryption in Java is by importing javax.crypto.Cipher, sun.misc.BASE64Decoder, sun.misc.BASE64Encoder and javax/crypto/SecretKey.

I did a lot research on those algorithms to understand the specific standards to make sure every step is the same in Java and Golang.

Since I cannot decrypt the encrypted data from java, I am trying to see the difference from encrypting in golang and that in Java to see the difference. The encrypted outputs from golang and Java are different even w/ the same format(24 digits with `"=="`at the end).

```
inputs: key: T3-Arghbegrgg455dfer4g==  
        text: 123456789012345  
output: golang: 07vl02WwI8dApjYI161TrQ==  
        java:   B9E8aoCd+fYQBkKbqCS3lA==
```

Please help to find out the reason behind the difference! Thanks!

The java code using

```java
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);

byte[] stringBytes = message.getBytes("UTF8");
byte[] raw = cipher.doFinal(stringBytes);

BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
String base64 = encoder.encode(raw);
return base64;
```

In Golang

```golang
block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
if err != nil {
    return "",err
}
content := []byte(src)
ecb := NewECBEncrypter(block)
content = PKCS5Padding(content, block.BlockSize())
crypted := make([]byte, len(content))
ecb.CryptBlocks(crypted, content)
finalMsg := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(crypted)
return finalMsg,nil
```

Comment: Not clear what u supposed to do? As I understand you are encrypted string using java `AES`. Not clear `golang`. Is you are trying to decrypt the same using golang ?

Comment: @ArtjomB. thanks for your reminder. Hope my modification can help people understand my problem better.

Comment: Your key looks like it's Base64-encoded. Did you decode it first or did you use it as-is (your code is incomplete in that regard)?

Comment: @hiteshghuge Yes, I am trying to encrypt in Java and decrypt in Go w/ the same data w/ the same key.  Fortunately, I cannot make it happen. In my question, I am trying to show the difference of encryption function and outputs in Java and Go.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Good Call. I did not write the Java code. The key seems like encoded based on base64. Will that be a problem if I use that key in Go for encryption or decryption?

Comment: @ArtjomB. Thanks. I tried PKCS7padding before. In Go, the encrypted results are exactly the same. BTW, I referred to a document about Java AES before, PKCS5padding is implemented by PKCS7padding

Comment: Right, I didn't missed that you're already using `PKCS5Padding`. Then we need to see your full code including how those inputs and outputs are handled.

Comment: Sorry, I have problem in posting my code because of formatting issues. Here are the libs I used in Go.                                                           
        _ "golang.org/x/crypto/blowfish"
 _ "github.com/andreburgaud/crypt2go/ecb"
 _ "github.com/andreburgaud/crypt2go/padding"
 "encoding/base64"

Comment: Note that `T3-Arghbegrgg455dfer4g==` seems to be **base64 url** format: normal base 64 doesn't contain a dash (`-`) only slashes and plus signs. Also note that using any class in `sun.misc` is explicitly forbidden by Java: these are internal implementation classes that may change any minute.

Comment: You need to show us how you generate the keys from the code, your code is currently incomplete. No doubt the libraries are OK, it's the rest of the code that is missing.